# How do I access TaxAgency's in IPP v3 API for QuickBooks Desktop?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How do I query for a list of Tax Agencies for QBD?

For QuickBooks Online, querying the TaxAgencies table works fine, but this doesn't work for connections that are using QBD.

In the documentation for QBD v3, I can see refers to AgencyRef type object, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation that elaborates on that further.

Answer (score 0):

QBO supports [tagAgency](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/taxagency) endpoint but QBD doesn't.

QBD supported entity Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v3/qbd_v3_reference/030_entity_services_reference

PN - QBD V3 APIs are already deprecated. It can't be used in near future.
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/09/08/timeline-to-discontinue-the-quickbooks-desktop-rest-api

Thanks